# No inserta datos SQlite

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Que tal colegas trato de hacer una inserción desde una Activity pero me da estos errores ¿Qué será?

```
public class HelperSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public String TABLACLIENTE = "CREATE TABLE Cliente(RFC TEXT PRIMARY KEY,  Nombre TEXT, Direccion TEXT, Telefono TEXT, Ciudad TEXT, Estado TEXT)";

public HelperSQLite(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version){
    super(context,name,factory,version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABLACLIENTE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

```
public class MainActivityClientes extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText Rfc;
EditText nom;
EditText direc;
EditText tel;
EditText ciu;
EditText esta;
Button btnRegistrar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_clientes);

    Rfc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtRfc);
    nom = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtNombre);
    direc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtDireccion);
    tel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTel);
    ciu = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtCIudad);
    esta = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtEstado);
    btnRegistrar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_registrar);
}

public void Agregar(View v){
    if(ComprobarCampos()){
        String rfc,nombre,direccion,telefono,ciudad,estado;
        rfc = Rfc.getText().toString();
        nombre = nom.getText().toString();
        direccion  = direc.getText().toString();
        telefono = tel.getText().toString();
        ciudad = ciu.getText().toString();
        estado = esta.getText().toString();

        HelperSQLite bh = new HelperSQLite(MainActivityClientes.this,"Cliente",null,1);
        if(bh != null){
            SQLiteDatabase db = bh.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues con = new ContentValues();
            con.put("RFC",rfc);
            con.put("Nombre",nombre);
            con.put("Direccion",direccion);
            con.put("Telefono",telefono);
            con.put("Ciudad",ciudad);
            con.put("Estado",estado);

            long insertado = db.insert("Cliente",null, con);

            if(insertado > 0 ){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivityClientes.this,"Datos guardados exitosamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivityClientes.this,"No se guardaron los datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivityClientes.this,"Existen campos vacios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public boolean ComprobarCampos(){
    if(Rfc.getText().toString().isEmpty() || nom.getText().toString().isEmpty() || direc.getText().toString().isEmpty() || tel.getText().toString().isEmpty() || ciu.getText().toString().isEmpty() || esta.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]}
Errores que me da:

Comment: Te sugiero primeramente revises lo que comento en mi respuesta @Locus0509 puede ser que creaste una estructura diferente antes de cambiar tu código.

Comment: Ese error puede darse por que existen otras bases con el mismo nombre y el motor se confunde con los tipos. valida si no intentas crear una base que ya existe anteriormente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que muestras:

> Datatype mismatch (code 20)

se debe a que estas insertando un tipo incorrectos en algún campo. Al parecer tu estructura

```
 "CREATE TABLE Cliente(RFC TEXT PRIMARY KEY,  Nombre TEXT, Direccion TEXT, Telefono TEXT, Ciudad TEXT, Estado TEXT)";
```

y los datos que insertas son correctos:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = bh.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues con = new ContentValues();
        con.put("RFC",rfc);
        con.put("Nombre",nombre);
        con.put("Direccion",direccion);
        con.put("Telefono",telefono);
        con.put("Ciudad",ciudad);
        con.put("Estado",estado);

        long insertado = db.insert("Cliente",null, con);
```

Te sugiero elimines la aplicación y la subas nuevamente para que en verdad aplique esta estructura de la BD.